# High availability web application - how to upgrade?

Tags: java, mysql, continuous-integration, high-availability

Our web application (spring + jpa + mysql) should have a very low downtime %.
currently we have a load balancer with a 3-tomcats cluster and session replication running the same web app with a single data source (mySQL).

That works great, in regard to availability.

But now,

We would like to upgrade our web application without issuing downtime.
The naive person will just say - shutdown one tomcat, deploy new version, and start it up again. (do for all tomcats) and you done!

However , when taking into consideration that 2 web apps variations will run at the same time (the old version and the newer version) we might gonna have some issues.

Can anyone shade some light on what are the critical aspects we should consider when trying to upgrade in real time? are there any good practices? any articles discussing these issues?

any help will do!

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: If you consider there might be issues because of your database or something else shared by all instances, consider there is no way to avoid a complete shutdown of your 3 instances before upgrade unless you duplicate your shared parts too to upgrade one instance after another but it seems difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several strategies for doing that. Here's two methods that I usually use -

1. Running both version side by side. As you said, this can cause issues. To do this you need to test in advance and see that you CAN run both side by side and that you don't have any data inconsistencies (due to changed schema etc.).
2. Replace running version. You can do this either by putting up a new tomcat cluster and then switching the load balancer. Or if you're not cloud based and you can't do that - take one or two servers out of the load balancer (preferably in low time so your application can handle the load). Replace the version on the servers that are out of traffic. Test test test that it's working. Place them into traffic again and take out the remaining servers, then update them.

Also, verify that you have a fast rollback method in case something is wrong with your version and you find it out only in production...

Comment: Toda for your reply Rotem, one quick question - if im adopting your methodology (no cloud) what about db updates?

Comment: Well, again, test beforehand that you don't screw anything not in the old version nor in the new, and that your new DB version can work with both :-)

I presume your DB has some redundancy (master-slave?). So one thing you can do is stop the replication, upgrade your slave. Put it back on and let the data replicate. Switch the slave to be the master (point your servers to work with it), switch the replication direction. Then do the same on the other instance.